# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php, if-statement

sorry , im newbie and bad at english , i google this problem still cant understand what is wrong , please help me !

i have this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

my code

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {$content_width:474} if ( ! function_exists( twentyfourteen_setup ) ) :
```

Comment: you might have missed semicolon before if statement

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Seems to me like your if statement syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Please go through some tutorial

Comment: It seems like you've missed semicolon before your if statement.

Comment: what is this $content_width:474 this is where the error occurs, i think you want to assign 474 to $content_width then change to $content_width=474 ; dont forget the semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$content_width:474` should be `$content_width=474;`